# Bokeh stack chart legend incorrect

Tags: python, bokeh, stacked-chart

i have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['<£5000', '£100K to £250K'],
               '01/01/2014': [8,1],
               '01/01/2015': [8,2],
               '01/01/2016': [7,1]})
```

I am creating a stacked chart in Bokeh. Creating the chart is fine, but the legend is incorrect.

```
grouped = df.groupby('Category')['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'].mean().round(0)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
countries = source.data['Category'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=countries)

p.vbar_stack(stackers=['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'],
         x='Category', source=source,
         legend = ['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'],
         width=0.5, color=Spectral3)


p.title.text ='Average Number of Trades by Portfolio Size'
p.legend.location = 'top_right'

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Portfolio Size'
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None  #remove the x grid lines

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Number of Trades'

show(p)
```

I think above in the line below, i have set the legend to the years. However as in the image, it has set to three points in the graph.

```
legend = ['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016']
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does show the right legend names if you put something else in the legend list, as long as it doesn't match the dates in your ColumnDataSource. So a simple fix for your problem is to add a space behind each date in the legend list.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral3

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['<£5000', '£100K to £250K'],
               '01/01/2014': [8,1],
               '01/01/2015': [8,2],
               '01/01/2016': [7,1]})


grouped = df.groupby('Category')['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'].mean().round(0)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped)
countries = source.data['Category'].tolist()
p = figure(x_range=countries)

p.vbar_stack(stackers=['01/01/2014', '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016'],
         x='Category', source=source,
         legend = ['01/01/2014 ', '01/01/2015 ', '01/01/2016 '],
         width=0.5, color=Spectral3)


p.title.text ='Average Number of Trades by Portfolio Size'
p.legend.location = 'top_right'

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Portfolio Size'
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None  #remove the x grid lines

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Number of Trades'

show(p)
```

[image]